# Exception Will Not Do What its Supposed to Do

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to get this exception to display an error box when an incorrect password is entered.

```
Public Class LoginException
    Inherits Exception
End Class
```

I am trying to write this program in Visual Basic

I have a Try...Catch statement that is supposed to display the error box.

```
Try
    Main.Login(txtUsername.Text, txtPassword.Text)
Catch ex As LoginException
    MessageBox.Show("Incorrect Password")
End Try
```

However, this Catch does not display the box. I have checked the `Main.Login` subroutine and it will display the confirmation box if the correct username and password are entered. I have called the exception, I am just struggling to figure out how to make the error box show.

UPDATE:

Here is the Login Sub

```
Sub Login(username As String, password As String)
        blnLoggedIn = False

        If VerifyUsername(username) And VerifyPassword(password) Then

            'Find index for username
            Dim userIndex As Integer
            For loopIndex = 0 To arrUsernames.Length - 1
                If arrUsernames(loopIndex) = username Then
                    userIndex = loopIndex
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
            'Check for password match
            If arrPasswords(userIndex) = password Then
                blnLoggedIn = True
            Else
                Throw New LoginException
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

UPDATE:

Here are the two functions that verify Username and Password
VerifyUsername & VerifyPassword

```
Function VerifyUsername(username As String) As Boolean
        If arrUsernames.Contains(username) Then
            Return True
        Else
            Return False
        End If
    End Function
    Function VerifyPassword(password As String) As Boolean
        If arrPasswords.Contains(password) Then
            Return True
        Else
            Return False
        End If
    End Function
    Public Class LoginException
        Inherits Exception
    End Class
```

Comment: Are you sure your Login method will throw exceptions?

Comment: Side note: Using exceptions for program flow control like in your example (invalid login) is considered bad practice.

Comment: @Filburt I don't think there's enough info here to raise that criticism.  I can imagine a workflow here where it's the best approach.

Comment: Probably need to see Main.Login() method to really understand what isn't working

Comment: @Avro I have edited my post with the Login Sub

Comment: So the next question, what VerifyUsername(username) and VerifyPassword(password) do?  Are you sure you code is getting past them into the actual authentication code where it can throw a LoginException?

Comment: And are you sure the index for  arrUsernames and arrPasswords even line up, seperate problem I think but that seems a very strange and potentially error prone way to authenticate

Comment: @Hursey I have pasted the two functions above. Before I added the exception whenever an incorrect password was entered, I had it say "incorrect Password" in a dialogue box. Now I'm trying to add an exception and it isn't functioning as before.

Comment: Just to double check, when you debug and step thru your code line by line, does it reach `Throw new LoginException' ?

Comment: @Craig I think the case is pretty clear: Throwing an exception if the entered password doesn't match the expected value is a book example of this anti-pattern. It's not forbidden to do that but it's still an anti-pattern.

Comment: @DeanOC How would I go about doing that?

Comment: @Mr_C_RL there are plenty of online resources showing how to debug VB.Net programs